# Update a value based on another dataframe pairing

Tags: python, pandas

I have problem where I need to update a value if people were at the same table.

```
 import pandas as pd
data = {"p1":['Jen','Mark','Carrie'],
       "p2":['John','Jason','Rob'],
       "value":[10,20,40]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["p1",'p2','value'])

meeting = {'person':['Jen','Mark','Carrie','John','Jason','Rob'],
          'table':[1,2,3,1,2,3]}
meeting = pd.DataFrame(meeting,columns=['person','table'])
```

`df` is a relationship table and `value` is the field i need to update. So if two people were at the same table in the `meeting` dataframe then update the `df` row accordingly.

for example: Jen and John were both at table 1, so I need to update the row in `df` that has Jen and John  and set their value to `value + 100` so 110.

I thought about maybe doing a self join on `meeting` to get the format to match that of `df` but not sure if this is the easiest or fastest approach

Comment: Can a person be at multiple tables in the meeting dataframe?

Comment: Can be more than 2 people at the same table?

Comment: yes more than 2 people will be at the table, no real limit on the number of people.technically yes, someone can be at multiple tables because i'm combining multiple days of meetings into one file. so on day 1 someone can be at table 1 and day 2 someone could be at table 2

Comment: `data` contains not all combinations of pairs between persons, shouldn't it be complete? Should the `data` be filled with new persons when they are appearing in `meeting`?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you could set the `person` as index in the `meeting` dataframe, and use its table values to replace the `names` in `df`. Then if both mappings have the same value (table), replace with `df.value+100`:

```
m = df[['p1','p2']].replace(meeting.set_index('person').table).eval('p1==p2')
df['value'] = df.value.mask(m, df.value+100)
```

---

```
print(df)

       p1     p2  value
0     Jen   John    110
1    Mark  Jason    120
2  Carrie    Rob    140
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be an approach, using `df.to_records()`:

```
groups=meeting.groupby('table').agg(set)['person'].to_list()
df['value']=[row[-1]+100  if set(list(row)[1:3]) in groups else row[-1] for row in df.to_records()]
```

Output:

```
df
       p1     p2  value
0     Jen   John    110
1    Mark  Jason    120
2  Carrie    Rob    140
```